# newrelic + django + gunicorn: worker timeout logged as SystemExit, is there a better way?

Tags: django, gunicorn, newrelic

I'm using newrelic with a Django application served by Gunicorn.
When one of my endpoints performs badly and times out, the normal gunicorn behavior is to send `SIGABRT` to the worker process, which then dies raising `SystemExit(1)`. This is normal.

These get logged as exceptions by Newrelic. I don't really want them cluttering up my application exception logs. It seems to me it would be more useful to view these in Newrelic as performance problems, rather than application errors.

Is there any way to 1) stop logging these as `SystemExit` exceptions, but 2) still see them as web transaction timeouts on the newrelic UI?